# model2-names.bst, unpublished reference and cites in the footnote

Tags: bibtex, urlbst

I am using `model2-names.bst` for the bibliographical style format. But I have found a couple of problems when using it. First, when I include an unpublished reference, with the web page where it is found, the following error appears:

```
! File ended while scanning use of \bibinfo......I suspect you have forgotten a `}', causing me
```

The problem occurs only when I include in JabRef in the note field the webpage for the reference like this: `\url{http://webpage.pdf}`. If I don´t include the webpage, the compilation works.

Additionally, the same error is found when I include cites in the footnote like this;

```
\footnote{ Text \citep{ref1, ref2, ref3, ref4}}
```

I included the following packages in my tex file

```
\documentclass[preprint,authoryear,12pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[centertags]{amsmath}
\usepackage[left=1in, right=1in, top=1in, bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage[flushmargin,multiple]{footmisc}
\usepackage[labelsep=period,font={bf},textfont={normalsize},labelfont={normalsize}]{caption}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}

\journal{Journal }

\begin{document}
```

Comment: Please provide more information, e.g., the full entry that contains a `note` field that features a URL string. Separately, since you're using the `model2-names` bibliography style, you could use the field named `url` (instead of the `note` field) to store the contents of the URL string.

Comment: Thank you, with your suggestion it works perfectly with the url.

Comment: OK, I'll make my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using the [model2-names](http://www.elsevier.com/author-schemas/the-elsarticle-latex-document-class) bibliography style, you could use the field named `url`, instead of the `note` field, to store the contents of the URL string. The `model2-names` bibliography style features detailed rules for typesetting URL strings stored in fields named `url`.